# How to make appropriate substitutions to prove this integral is locally integrable

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

Now take $\mathbb C^2$, consider $s$, $t$ complex variables. Then how can I show (or how to make appropriate substitutions to show)
$$\int_s\int_t\frac{1}{|s-t^2|}d\lambda$$ is locally (near origin) integrable?